# Equivalence of partial sums in strictly ordered sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, set-theory, order-theory

While carrying out a task, the following question arose.

Suppose we have two sets of positive numbers, $C_1$ and $C_2$ respectively. In which it is fulfilled:

- $C_1$ and $C_2$ have an equivalent order, example: $C_1 = \lbrace 1, 10, 20, 40 \rbrace$ and $C_2 = \lbrace 90, 1000, 5000, 10000 \rbrace$. The equivalent of 1 in $C_2$ is 90, the equivalent of 10 in $C_2$ is 1000, etc. The important thing is that 1 < 10 and, equivalently, 90 < 1000 and so on with $\textbf{all elements and their relationships} $
- $|C_1| = |C_2|$
- In both $C_1$ and $C_2$ there are no repeated elements

Let $S_1^{m}$ and $S_2^{m}$ be the $\textbf{sum sets}$ of $C_1$ and $C_2$ that have $m$ elements respectively.
Given the two sets of sums, let's say they are ordered. That is to say: if $C_1 = \lbrace 1, 10, 20, 40 \rbrace$ and $C_2 = \lbrace 90, 1000, 5000, 10000 \rbrace$ and $m=3$ then $S_1^m = \{ 31 , 51, 70\}$ and $S_2^m = \{ 6090, 11090, 16000 \}$.

Let $s_i$ and $s_j$ be a particular sum in $S_1^m$ and $S_2^m$ (i and j are the indices that correspond to each sum in the respective sum set).

In this context, I would like to know:
if $s_i$ and $s_j$ take elements at the same indices of each corresponding set then $i=j$, that is, the partial sums that take elements at the same indices of the sets are located at the same index in the respective sets of partial sums even though the elements of the sum are different.

It should be noted that I am not talking about the literal sum, that is, if the elements add 500, 1094, etc. but the equivalence between orders of particular numbers is transferred to their sums and combinations.

Please, if someone could answer me, I would be very grateful since it has been on my mind and seems simple.

Comment: Why isn't $61$ in $S_1^3$ and $15090$ in $S_2^3$ in your example? In any case, I don't think your proposed statement is true: consider $m=2$ and the sets $\{1,3,10,11\}$ and $\{1,2,3,10\}$.

Comment: The first and second conditions on the two sets are equivalent for finite sets of numbers. If two sets are the same size, then you can always match up the numbers as described in the first condition, And the first condition establishes a 1-1 correspondence between the sets, demonstrating that they are the same size. And your third condition is simply that you have *sets*, as you'd already said, instead of some other collection. Elements are either in a set or not in the set. There is no "in it mulitple times".